# checkbox checked not working at first moment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkbox and one is checked form the beginning, but is not doing what is supposed to do, so I have to unchecked and check it again to make it work, how can I make it work from the start ?

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
  
  function text(obj) {
  if($(obj).is(":checked")){  
    var x=($(obj).attr('id'));
    if (x=='a'){
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'something here a';      
    }else {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'something here b';    
    }

  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Load D3 -->
     </head>
    <body>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input id="a" type="checkbox" class="radio" value='des' name="fooby[1][]" checked="" onchange='text(this)'/>option a</label>
          <label>
            <input id="b" type="checkbox" class="radio"  value='icv' name="fooby[1][]" onchange='text(this)'/>option b</label>
        </div>
        <p id="text"></p>
     
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: So just as an explanation, you understand that on page load all you are doing is making a click event binding, right?  And the actual logic of the event handler will not happen until the event happens, right?

Comment: there is no `event` in `HTML` which can listen is checkbox checked when the dom was getting ready. So you can write your own checkbox implementation or apply some code in `ready` function

Comment: honestly no, I don't. I'm kind of new in this.

Comment: `$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {` <= ok, so what this logic is doing is finding all `<input>` elements on the page that also have a `type="checkbox"`.  It is then adding a click event handler to every one of them.  What that does is, from that point on, *in the future*, any click event that happens on those elements will be processed by that logic.  But for that to happen, the click event must happen.  A click event does not happen on page load.  A click event happens when the user clicks on something.  So the actual body of the event handler does not happen on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I play with some trick

just focus on this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkboxes.each(function(index, value){
    if($(value).is(':checked')){
      $(value).click( ); // by default checked. if click now check box will be unchecked
       $(value).click( );// above line uncheck the checkbox  now we have to check it again, because this is what all we want 
    }
  })
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkboxes.each(function(index, value){
    if($(value).is(':checked')){
      $(value).click( ); // by default checked. if click now check box will be unchecked
       $(value).click( );// above line uncheck the checkbox  now we have to check it again, because this is what all we want 
    }
  })
});

$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
  
  function text(obj) {
  if($(obj).is(":checked")){  
    var x=($(obj).attr('id'));
    if (x=='a'){
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'something here a';      
    }else {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'something here b';    
    }

  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Load D3 -->
     </head>
    <body>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input id="a" type="checkbox" class="radio" value='des' name="fooby[1][]" checked="" onchange='text(this)'/>option a</label>
          <label>
            <input id="b" type="checkbox" class="radio"  value='icv' name="fooby[1][]" onchange='text(this)'/>option b</label>
        </div>
        <p id="text"></p>
     
    </body>
    
</html>
```